# Software Center Crash 13.04

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, ppa

I'm having problems with the Ubuntu Software Center, when I try to open it, after two seconds it closes. I've tried reinstalling it but I keep getting this when I try sudo apt-get update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/software-store-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/software-store-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are generally not relevant to these sorts of "problems" unless the file was edited by hand. Adding PPAs via `add-apt-repository` or `software-sources` typically adds them to a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` rather than in `sources.list` directly (which really should be kept pristine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages aren't really errors. They are simply telling you that that PPA does not support your version of Ubuntu. They are not preventing you from just running `sudo apt-get install software-center` which will still work.

Remove that PPA (`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/software-store-developers/ppa/ubuntu raring main`) from your sources. It is no longer in use. Updated versions of `software-center` are provided via the `Ubuntu One` team's PPAs:

- `ppa:ubuntuone/stable`
- `ppa:ubuntuone/beta`
- `ppa:ubuntuone/nightlies`

These PPAs include the Ubuntu One client packages, Software Center, and any necessarily updated dependencies. However, the version of `software-center` in Ubuntu 13.04 is still pretty much up to date, as it was only released a couple months ago.

Comment: So, which ones do I have to remove? And, more important, how? I'm a newbie

Answer (score -1):

you can add them by copy and pasting them into the other software tab of the software and updates section of system settings. Click the gear in the top right corner to get to system settings.